# Why $n=1$ in Bragg' s condition?

Tags: condensed-matter, diffraction, x-rays, braggs-law

While studying XRD pattern , most of the time we use n= 1 in the Bragg equation. Why we prefer n=1? Why don't we use n = 2 or 3 ?

Comment: the path difference  between layers of atoms are of the  order  of  x-ray wavelength...perhaps that decides ..

Comment: That looks like it should be an answer

Comment: Discussion at https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_the_first_order_of_diffraction_more_important_than_others_n1 seems relevant. I like some of the arguments there, but I am not sure which of them is correct:-)

Comment: There are "higher order" contributions for $n \neq 1$. They are just weaker in intensity (as is explained in the link, which I just realized).